# simulating the non-blocking cpu_percent using pyqt5 QTimer

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, psutil, qtimer

I am trying to show the `cpu_percent` of a process (p) using `p.cpu_percent()`. If I use the block (interval=2), the GUI hangs out, but If I use non-block (interval=None), the first call is always (0%). So I simulated it as follwoing:

```
pid = '....'
p   = psutil.Process(pid) # some process I have
with p.oneshot():
     cpu = p.cpu_percent(interval=None)
label = QLabel()
label.setText(cpu)

# call this later
p   = psutil.Process(pid) # some process I have
with p.oneshot():
     cpu = p.cpu_percent(interval=None)
QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: label.setText(cpu)
```

But the results of updating the `cpu_percent()` with the `singleshot` is really large 30%, while the actual cpu-usage should be like .1% (checked from the Task manager). Why this approach gives fake large `cpu_percent()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating the cpu value with the timer, you're just delaying `setText()`: the second `cpu_percent()` is still called at start up.

Make a function that includes the `with` block *and* calls `setText`, and use that function for QTimer:

```
def updateLabel():
    with p.oneshot():
         label.setText(p.cpu_percent(interval=None))

QTimer.singleShot(1000, updateLabel)
```